# Failed sending an email to outlook account using SQL server management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, database-mail

I have been trying to send an email to my outlook account using SQL server management studio but keep facing with error like: *The smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated 5.7.57; client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [__.prod.outlook.com]* even though I have ensured that everything was inputted correctly.

Here's the query:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO

sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp  
    @profile_name = 'Test_Email',  
    @description = 'Profile used for sending outgoing notifications using Outlook.' ;  
GO


EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp  
    @profile_name = 'Test_Email',  
    @principal_name = 'public',  
    @is_default = 1 ;
GO

EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp  
    @account_name = 'Outlook',  
    @description = 'Mail account for sending outgoing notifications.',  
    @email_address = 'mail@mycompany.com',  
    @display_name = 'Automated Mailer',  
    @mailserver_name = 'smtp.office365.com',
    @port = 587,
    @enable_ssl = 1,
    @username = 'mail@mycompany.com',
    @password = 'password' ;  
GO

-- Add the account to the profile  
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp  
    @profile_name = 'Test_Email',  
    @account_name = 'Outlook',  
    @sequence_number =1 ;  
GO

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
     @profile_name = 'Test_Email',
     @recipients = 'mail@mycompany.com',
     @body = 'The database mail configuration was completed successfully.',
     @subject = 'Automated Success Message';
GO

sp_configure 'show advanced', 1; 
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure;
GO


SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log;
```

Can anyone advise what went wrong?

Thank you in advance!

*Edited: Added @ to email addresses!*

Comment: Does the password have any special characters?

Comment: I don't see any `@` characters in your e-mail addresses. Have you tried using correct e-mail addresses? Welcome to DBA.SE.

Comment: @Johnakahot2use Hi! I have @ in my email addresses. Sorry for the confusion that I missed out when I was replacing them. Will add them in to prevent confusion.

Comment: @RandolphWest Hi, yes! it has an exclamation mark, does it have an effect?